# Appending using sed pattern after certain line number

Tags: sed

I am using following command to append string after AMP, but now I want to add after to AMP which is after SET2 or line number 9, can we modify this command to append the string only after SET2 or line number 9? And if I want to add to only to SET1 AMPs or before line number 9 , could someone help me with the command, thanks.

```
$ sed -i '/AMP/a Target4' test.txt
$ cat test.txt 
#SET1
AMP
Target 1
Target 2
AMP
Target 3
Target 4
Target 5
#Set2
AMP
Target 11
Target 12
```

Note there is no line between above text.

Comment: Should the new text appear directly below the third "AMP", on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
sed -i '
/^#Set2/,${     ;# if the line starts with "#Set2", execute the {block} until the last line $
/AMP/a Target4  ;# append the string after "AMP"
}               ;# end of the block
' test.txt
```

If you want to append the string **before** the `#Set2` line, please try:

```
sed -i '
1,/^#Set2/ {    ;# excecute the {block} while the line number >= 1 until the line matches the pattern /^#Set2/
/AMP/a Target4
}
' test.txt
```

The expression `address1,address2` is a `flip-flop` operator. Once the
`address1` (line number, regular expression, or other condition) meets,
the operator keeps on returning `true` until the `address2` meets.
Then the following command or block is executed from `address1` until
`address2`.

Comment: First one worked but for before SET2 command, it is showing following error  sed -i '1,/^#Set2/ ${/AMP/a Target4}' test.txt sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown command: `$'

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Please note there is *not* the `$` character just before `{`. in my 2nd answer. It may be better to use cut&paste to copy the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to after AMP which is after `#Set2` **or line number 9**,
I think it is better to process up to the 8th line and after the 9th line separately.

For example, the command is below:

```
sed '
1,8{
  /^#Set2/,${
    /AMP/a Target4
  }
}
9,${
  /AMP/a Target4
}' test.txt
```